# How can I schedule an import into dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a group of dynamo tables exporting to s3 on a nightly basis. It was easy creating the export to s3 to be recurring.
When I setup the import process it only allows for a one time import.
How does one setup an import process to be recurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work with AWS data pipelines

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I did setup datapipeline, which utilizes EMR. There's a built in template in datapipeline for this use. Pretty easy to configure, and it even warns you when you have a configuration error.